# gcc | compile from source trouble

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, configure

I try compile simple tool, and get error. Help me please fix it :)

```
./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for g++... g++
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
....
....
checking for main in -lboost_filesystem... no
configure: error: in `/root/tbb2mbox/mbox2eml-0.1.2':
configure: error: boost_filesystem is required
```

but boost, boost-devel is installed

```
boost-1.33.1-16.el5_9
boost-devel-1.33.1-16.el5_9
```

libs

```
ldconfig -p | grep boost_filesystem
        libboost_filesystem.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so.2
```

headers

```
rpm -ql boost-devel | grep filesystem

/usr/include/boost/filesystem
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/config.hpp
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/convenience.hpp
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/exception.hpp
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/path.hpp
/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a
/usr/lib64/libboost_filesystem.so
```

What i can do for success ? ))

Comment: It don't see how this is relevant to c++ or gcc, as this is purely a bug in the configure script, isn't it?

Comment: Version 1.33.1

December 5th, 2006 12:00 GMT

Comment: Maybe build newer version of boost from src?

Answer (score 0):

When `configure` performs a test, it generally only reports the results to the terminal.  However, it also logs most of the work it does to `config.log`.

So, when confronted with an error like this, the best thing to do is search through `config.log` to find the failing compilation.  This will give you more information about exactly what has failed, which should let you fix the underlying problem.